# using urllib to import formatted text file with lines out of column

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to use `urllib` to parse a text file from the website and pull in data. There are other files that I have been able to do, they're text formatted in columns, but this one is kind of throwing me because of the line for Southern Illinois-Edwardsville pushes the second score and location out of the column.

```
file = urllib.urlopen('http://www.boydsworld.com/cgi/scores.pl?team1=all&team2=all&firstyear=2011&lastyear=2011&format=Text&submit=Fetch')

for line in file:
    game_month = line[0:1].rstrip()
    game_day   = line[2:4].rstrip()
    game_year  = line[5:9].rstrip()
    team1      = line[11:37].rstrip()
    team1_scr  = line[38:40].rstrip()
    team2      = line[42:68].rstrip()
    team2_scor = line[68:70].rstrip()
    extra_info = line[72:100].rstrip()
```

The Southern Illinois-Edwardsville line imports 'il' as team2_scr and imports '  4  @Central Arkansas' as the extra_info.

Comment: Never ever use volatile services like dpaste for referencing code!

Comment: I take it your football data didn't really come from 'foo.com'? Without seeing the original data, it's hard to give you any advice.

Comment: You have a problem with parsing? Show us what are you trying to parse. You have a problem with data output? Show us how data is output correctly, and what goes wrong.

Comment: Sorry guys, left the data out, too early, not enough coffee yet. I edited the post and added the URL. There are several instances of Southern Illinois-Edwardsville in the file, the first instance is on Line 17.

Comment: As a general rule, use `str.split` or some other form of parsing instead of using absolute character indexes which are much more likely to change than the delimiter is - and I would rather have `month, day, year, ... = (s.strip() for s in line.split('  ') if s)` than what you've got.

Comment: You should use regular expression (`re` module), it's the only way to parse it.

Comment: @Chris Morgan There are lines with only one space between cols.

Comment: @DrTyrsa: arg, so I see. "North Carolina-Greensboro 10". That would then get much more messy, allowing split on one character if `len() == 25`, or something like that... Really, I think it's just a bad data source.

Comment: Ouch. It's not even that neat. It would get to seeing if it'll split into five and if not see whether the number's got tacked on to `team1` or `team2` or what... quite possible, but getting steadily messier and more unpleasant (and losing any advantage of `csv` as so much parsing has to be done in this step - writing your own iterator and class type would be simpler).

Comment: @Chris Morgan Look at my answer. :-)

Comment: @DrTyrsa: now that was a sensible approach... if I'd been more interested in the problem itself rather than just as a coding exercise, I would have looked around.  You win, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Wanna see the best solution? http://www.boydsworld.com/cgi/scores.pl?team1=all&team2=all&firstyear=2011&lastyear=2011&format=CSV&submit=Fetch will give you nice CSV file, no dark magic needed.

Answer (score 0):

Say that `s` contains one row of your table. Then you could use the split() method of the `re` (regular expressions) library:

```
import re
rexp = re.compile('  +')  # Match two or more spaces
cols = rexp.split(s)
```

...and cols is now a list of strings, each a column in your table row. This assumes that table columns are separated by at least two spaces, and nothing else. If that is not the case, the argument to re.compile() can be edited to allow for other configurations.

Recall that Python considers a file a sequence of lines, separated by newline characters. Therefore, all you have to do is to for-loop over your file, applying .split() to each line.

For an even nicer solution, check out the built-in map() function and try using that instead of a for-loop.

Comment: `['New', 'Mexico', 'State']` and so on.

Comment: @jforberg It won't work because there are lines with only one space between cols.

Comment: @DrTyrsa: More than a few? If there are, I don't see how it's possible to parse it mechanically in an easy way.

Comment: @jforberg It's easy, look at my answer. :-)

Comment: @DrTyrsa: Yes, of course :) but it's not much fun!
BTW, there are 40 irregular lines. If I had to solve it without using your solution, the easiest way would probably be to edit those lines manually.

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like this:

```
def get_row(row):
    row=row.split()
    num_pos=[]
    for i in range(len(row)):
        try:
            int(row[i])
            num_pos.append(i)
        except:
            pass
    assert(len(num_pos)==2)
    ans=[]
    ans.append(row[0])
    ans.append("".join(row[1:num_pos[0]]))
    ans.append(int(row[num_pos[0]]))
    ans.append("".join(row[num_pos[0]+1:num_pos[1]]))
    ans.append(int(row[num_pos[1]]))
    ans.append("".join(row[num_pos[1]+1:]))
    return ans


row1="2/18/2011  Central Arkansas           5  Southern Illinois-Edwardsville  4  @Central Arkansas"
row2="2/18/2011  Central Florida           11  Siena                      1  @Central Florida"

print get_row(row1)
print get_row(row2)
```

output:

```
['2/18/2011', 'CentralArkansas', 5, 'SouthernIllinois-Edwardsville', 4, '@CentralArkansas']
['2/18/2011', 'CentralFlorida', 11, 'Siena', 1, '@CentralFlorida']
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you just need to split on multiple spaces. Unfortunately the `csv` module only allows a single-character delimiter, but `re.sub` can help. I would recommend something like this:

```
import urllib2
import csv
import re

u = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.boydsworld.com/cgi/scores.pl?team1=all&team2=all&firstyear=2011&lastyear=2011&format=Text&submit=Fetch')

reader = csv.DictReader((re.sub(' {2,}', '\t', line) for line in u), delimiter='\t', fieldnames=('date', 'team1', 'team1_score', 'team2', 'team2_score', 'extra_info'))

for i, row in enumerate(reader):
    if i == 5: break  # Only do five (otherwise you don't need ``enumerate()``)
    print row
```

This produces results like this:

```
{'team1': 'Air Force', 'team2': 'Missouri State', 'date': '2/18/2011', 'team2_score': '2', 'team1_score': '7', 'extra_info': '@neutral'}
{'team1': 'Akron', 'team2': 'Lamar', 'date': '2/18/2011', 'team2_score': '1', 'team1_score': '2', 'extra_info': '@neutral'}
{'team1': 'Alabama', 'team2': 'Alcorn State', 'date': '2/18/2011', 'team2_score': '0', 'team1_score': '11', 'extra_info': '@Alabama'}
{'team1': 'Alabama State', 'team2': 'Tuskegee', 'date': '2/18/2011', 'team2_score': '5', 'team1_score': '9', 'extra_info': '@Alabama State'}
{'team1': 'Appalachian State', 'team2': 'Maryland-Eastern Shore', 'date': '2/18/2011', 'team2_score': '0', 'team1_score': '4', 'extra_info': '@Appalachian State'}
```

Or if you prefer, just use a `cvs.reader` and get `list`s rather than `dict`s:

```
reader = csv.reader((re.sub(' {2,}', '\t', line) for line in u), delimiter='\t')

print reader.next()
```

Comment: With this in its current state 40 rows get messed up and `extra_info is None`, due to there only being one space rather than two. See my comment on the question for how that could be mainly fixed